# How to mock FileWriter in Junit 5

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit5, jmockit

I am trying to mock a FileWriter so that my test will not create the file. The code is running ordinary but I can not create a proper test.

JSONExporter

```
    public void exportFile(List<Employee> employeeList) throws ExportFileException {
    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter("filepath")) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()  //prints the json file with json indenting
                .create();
        gson.toJson(employeeList, writer);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ExportFileException();
    }
}
```

TestJSONExporter

```
 @Injectable FileWriter mockedFileWriter;
@Test
void testExportFile_whenFilenameIsValid_willDoNothing(@Mocked Gson mockedGson) throws IOException {
    new Expectations() {{
        new FileWriter(anyString); result = mockedFileWriter;
        mockedGson.toJson(any, (FileWriter) any);
    }};
    Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow( () -> jsonFileExporter.exportFile("filename", Role.SELLER, employeeList));
}
```

Console

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (Result too large)

at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
at com.eurodyn.training.export.JSONFileExporterTest$1.<init>(JSONFileExporterTest.java:59)
at com.eurodyn.training.export.JSONFileExporterTest.testExportFile_whenFilenameIsValid_willDoNothing(JSONFileExporterTest.java:58)
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do it with either jmockit or mockito. PowerMock is not compatible with JUnit 5 i think.

Comment: `@Injectable` gives your test a mocked `FileWriter` instance, but that is not the same as the future instance created with `new FileWriter(...)`, which is *not* mocked. Instead of trying to mock, write a real test which just writes a (small) file and then reads it for verification.

Comment: thanks for the response @Rogério. I managed to do this by mocking the Constructor of the super class of FileWriter. I found that by mocking FIle() the file did not be created.